# Xorg troubles on Debian

Tags: drivers, xorg, debian-wheezy

I was trying to install some ATI drivers on a Debian Wheezy install and messed up my X server. The commands I ran were:

```
wget --referer=http://www2.ati.com http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip
unzip amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run --force
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf && aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

After this occurred, I was not able to get to a graphical interface on tty7. I can still get to a terminal on tty1.

The issue seems to be that I deleted the xorg.conf, so I have since ran `Xorg -reconfigure` and this has generated a new file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but now, whenever I get to tty7, all I get is a blinking cursor that doesn't do anything. Any tips or tricks on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

This is self-explanatory, I believe.